# Array merge recursively php

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone tell me how i can convert the first array to second array using php array operations.

First array :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [actual_release_date] => 2013-06-07 00:00:00
            [distributors] => 20th Century Fox / 20th Century Fox Animation / Fox 2000 Pictures / Fox Searchlight
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [actual_release_date] => 2013-06-28 11:11:00
            [distributors] => 20th Century Fox / 20th Century Fox Animation / Fox 2000 Pictures / Fox Searchlight
        )
)
```

Second array:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [actual_release_date] => array( 0=>2013-06-07 00:00:00 , 1=> 2013-06-28 11:11:00 )
            [distributors] => 20th Century Fox / 20th Century Fox Animation / Fox 2000 Pictures / Fox Searchlight
        )
)
```

If the second element is common, and first element is different, then we have to group it in one array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try plain old `foreach` with an `if` inside?

Comment: And if both fields are common?

Comment: @Jack only one will be in actual_release_date

Comment: @VtrioAjeesh In that case, Baba's solution will not give the correct results for that scenario. Just fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$data = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a[$b['distributors']])) {
        $a[$b['distributors']]['actual_release_date'][] = $b['actual_release_date'];
    } else {
        $a[$b['distributors']]['actual_release_date'] = array($b['actual_release_date']);
        $a[$b['distributors']]['distributors'] = $b['distributors'];
    }
    return $a;
}, array());

print_r(array_values($data));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [actual_release_date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-06-07 00:00:00
                    [1] => 2013-06-28 11:11:00
                )

            [distributors] => 20th Century Fox / 20th Century Fox Animation / Fox 2000 Pictures / Fox Searchlight
        )

)
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33524)

Answer (score -1):

You try try array marge..

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
//Maerge them
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Learn more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

The documentation says:

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the
>   first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array
>   and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

> The keys from the first array will be preserved. If an array key
>   exists in both arrays, then the element from the first array will be
>   used and the matching key's element from the second array will be
>   ignored.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
}
```